# How can I detect when the Backspace key is long pressed?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm working on an iOS project and I'm trying to detect when the backspace key is long pressed.

I'm using an UITextView filled with a lot of text and then I keep the backspace key pressed. First the text is removed char by char and then the whole text is deleted.

I'm using this method to detect all changes :

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
```

I observed that while the text is deleted  char by char, this method is called, but when the whole text is deleted nothing happens.

Any thoughts on this ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

This will detect backspace

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (textField==txtMobileNo)
    {

        const char * _char = [string cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        int isBackSpace = strcmp(_char, "\b");

        if (isBackSpace == -8) {
            NSLog(@"isBackSpace");

            return YES; // is backspace
        }
        else if (textField.text.length == 10) {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom back key (or overlay a view on top of the standard one) and then use UITouch. So check when touchesBegan and start a timer which deletes a character from the string every x seconds. When touchedEnd kill the timer.